# ReferenceError: result is not defined on invoking SQL Adapter Procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Why if I write this:

```
function selectListaArticoliOrdineCliente(n_ordine,cod_cli){
    var invocationData={
            adapter : 'DB2Adapter',
            procedure: 'selectListaArticoliOrdineCliente',
            parameters:[n_ordine,cod_cli]
        };

         WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,
        {
             onSuccess: function(){
                 getAllDettaglioOrdine(result);
             },
              onFailure: function(){
                  WL.Logger.debug("fallito");

              }

        }       
        );
}
```

or write this

```
function selectListaArticoliOrdineCliente(n_ordine,cod_cli){
    ....
         WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,
        {
             onSuccess:  getAllDettaglioOrdine(result);
             ,
              onFailure: function(){
                  WL.Logger.debug("fallito");

              }

        }       
        );
}
```

the  result variable is not defined, but if I write this

```
 function selectListaArticoliOrdineCliente(n_ordine,cod_cli){
        ....
             WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,
            {
                 onSuccess:  getAllDettaglioOrdine
                 ,
                  onFailure: function(){
                      WL.Logger.debug("fallito");

                  }

            }       
            );
    }
```

All work perfectly?! How I pass another parameter to onSuccessFunction? For example i would pass result and an id.Such as

```
 onSuccess:  getAllDettaglioOrdine(result,"9000000")
```

The function getAllDettagioOrdine

```
function getAllDettaglioOrdine(result,id_ordine){

    ordine_cliente_dettaglio_articolo=result.invocationResult.resultSet;
```

..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're calling a function instead of defining a callback.

Change this:

`onSuccess:  getAllDettaglioOrdine(result,"9000000")`

to this:

`onSuccess: function(result){ getAllDettaglioOrdine(result,"9000000") }`